# Faded windows 10 cursor

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor, bug

It's hard to explain, basically I noticed that my cursor, compared to other cursors I see online, is almost all white with no black borders to highlight the cursor. I searched if anyone was having the same problem as me, but no one has this problem.

[image: Faded windows 10 cursor]

I can't attach the photo because it doesn't give a good idea, but I'm attaching a photo of how the cursor should look normally.

Comment: Did setting the mouse solve your problem?

Comment: I tried the method to change the color because there is always this problem like it's blurry, a dull color, if you know what i mean

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install using the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  Use the option to Keep Everything to start with.

Answer (score 2):

look in Settings > Ease of Access > Mouse Pointer

The default in Windows 10 is 'White' with black borders. Other pointer color options could be changing what you see, but they do all have the same size border

[image: defaults]

other options are in Settings > Devices > Mouse > Additional mouse options > Pointers tab:

[image: Mouse Properties]

You can set "Use Default" here to fix any weird changes, or enable the pointer shadow to make it easier to see

The default windows cursor image files are stored in `C:\Windows\Cursors\`